# Co-op quests count in single player?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

Does the progress of campaign or side-quest missions carry over to single player?

Do I have to host the online game for it to count towards my single player campaign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and the other way around too. Any mission (that the player has completed all the prerequisite missions for) can be competed in either mode.